# Deployed modified sample app on Bluemix - it shows the sample's index.html instead of my index.jsp

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I have created sample web application using Liberty Java. Download & import the code in my eclipse. Remove the default index.html & `index.js`. Created my own `index.jsp` & mention welcome page in `web.xml`.
While pushing on cloud it shows it old default `index.html` instead of my `index.jsp`. I try by clean & push using CF plugin in eclipse.
Please lets us know how to resolve this issue .

Comment: Hello Ram, I did the your suggested approach but still it showing default index.html instead of my new index.jsp. As I already told I deleted the index.html & index.js from the template project & added my index.jsp as welcome page. It is running fine on Tomcat Server but not on bluemix.

Comment: Can you post your `web.xml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to go into the Bluemix app and explicitly remove the `index.html` file.  If you are using Git, then while you may have committed your changes, you may not have pushed your changes.